# Appending a collection of new bytes

Tags: java

I have a server that sends bytes back to a client app, when the client app receives a finished response from the server i want to gather the bytes before the finish response comes back to the client. How do i append theses bytes back together again.

So when the bytes are sent to the server these bytes are split up into segments of say 100 bytes and when the server sends the bytes back to the client i want to to gather these segments back into its normal form again.

I have had a look at Concatenating to arrays but is there a simple way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could create a [`ByteArrayOutputStream`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/ByteArrayOutputStream.html), then [`write()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/ByteArrayOutputStream.html#write%28byte%5B%5D,%20int,%20int%29) the arrays to it, and finally use [`toByteArray()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/ByteArrayOutputStream.html#toByteArray%28%29).

Answer (score 1):

[Guava](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com)'s `Bytes` class provides a [Bytes.concat](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/v10.0.1/javadoc/com/google/common/primitives/Bytes.html#concat%28byte%5B%5D...%29) method, though it's more useful when you have a fixed number of arrays you want to concatenate than if you're gathering a variable number of arrays to concatenate. `ByteArrayOutputStream` is *probably* what you want here, though, based on your description, because it doesn't require you to keep each individual array you receive around in order to concatenate them... you can just add them to the output stream.